# Is there something better than reCaptcha?

Tags: recaptcha

I've implemented reCaptcha on my site but whenever I test it out it takes me like 3-5 tries before I'm successful.  I don't think my users will like this.  I noticed some sites have questions like "What is 2 + 2?"  Is something like that just as effective?

Comment: Have a look at [CAPTCHA-less Security](http://www.karlgroves.com/2012/04/03/captcha-less-security/) for some ways to replace them. As for "2+2" or honeypots (in which a blind people or somebody reading it without CSS wouldn't fail), they're OK as long as you aren't Google! ;) The bots I encountered were really really dumb, they just tried and tried again.

Comment: @FelipeAls Could you post your comment as an answer.  I found it really helpful and the information should be preserved from link rot.  Besides, it gets better points for upvote :)

Comment: @NathanielJohnson Sure. I only found closed questions older than this one and/or older than the article from K. Groves and he did an useful work.

Answer (score 2):

Comment posted as an answer:

Have a look at [CAPTCHA-less Security](http://www.karlgroves.com/2012/04/03/captcha-less-security/) for some ways to replace them.

As for "2+2" or honeypots (in which a blind people or somebody reading it without CSS wouldn't fail), they're OK as long as you aren't Google! ;) (i.e. a high-profile target)
The bots I encountered were really really dumb, they just tried and tried again.

---

K. Groves, the author of the above article and accessibility consultant, also collected a [List of Resources: Breaking CAPTCHA](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/02/09/list-of-resources-breaking-captcha/)

> A list of (28) resources (he) dug up that illustrate that CAPTCHA isn’t the security silver bullet people think they are.

From another point of view, User eXperience (yep, CAPTCHAs annoy users *a lot*. Angry fleeing people...), googling "ux captcha" seems quite effective, for example these answers from UX SE: [Does Captcha Really Affect UX?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33211/does-captcha-really-affect-ux)